# ¿Como puedo acceder a una label desde otra clase?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Creo que la pregunta es sencilla, tengo dos clases. Siento si la forma de programar el tema del hilo es un poco chapucera.

La cosa es esta clase lanza un hilo que hace referencia a el metodo `abrirTTelnet();` de la clase  `Telnet server`, ¿Como puedo hacer para que desde la clase telnet pueda tener acceso a `label1.text` de `Form1.cs`?

Lo que quiero es poder modificar desde la clase Telnet a una label de la clase Form1

La clase telnet abre un socket a un servidor y este servidor me empieza a enviar una especie de log con un tipo de valor numérico, quiero que cada vez que el valor cambie pueda modificar el texto de el label, eso lo tengo controlado, lo que no consigo es poder modificar el label desde la clase telnet.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Boolean activo = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart delegado = new ThreadStart(proceso1);
        Thread hilo = new Thread(delegado);


        if (activo)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hilo abortado");
            hilo.Abort();
            activo = false;
        }
        else
        {
            hilo.Start();
            activo = true;
        }
    }


    private void proceso1()
    {
        TelnetServer.abrirTelnet();
    }
}
```

Un ejemplo de lo que hay en mi clase telnet.

```
public class TelnetServer{

    public static void abrirTelnet(){

      //Aquí habría whiles, condiciones y cosas.  


      if(Si_esta_condicion_se_cumple){
      //Aquí es donde querría hacer referencia a Form1.label.text = data;
      label1.text = "Un string cualquiera"; 
     }

     }
}
```

Comment: Pero esa clase telnet es propia? No lo acabo de ver... Si tu problema es acceder a un label desde otra clase tienes 2 opciones: o le pasas el label por el constructor a la clase telnet o te creas un evento que lo dispares desde la clase telnet y desde tu clase principal lo recoges y haces los cambios que quieras. Personalmente prefiero la segunda forma

Comment: La clase TelnetServer es una clase mía que abre un socket blablabla, me podrías explicar como es eso de pasar el label o como hacer el disparador? No tengo ni idea...

Comment: Lo que no me queda claro es, desde la clase Telnet quieres acceder a un label de Form1 o desde Form1 quieres acceder a un label de Telnet?

Comment: Quiero acceder desde la clase Telnet a una label de Form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlo con eventos es sencillo, te muestro como:

Clase Telnet

```
public class TelnetServer{

   public delegate void pasoDatosHandler(string num);  //Declaramos el delegado indicando que vamos a mandar un string
   public event pasoDatosHandler OnPasoDatos;  //Declaramos el evento

   public void abrirTelnet(){

      //Aquí habría whiles, condiciones y cosas.  
      if(Si_esta_condicion_se_cumple){
       //Aquí es donde querría hacer referencia a Form1.label.text = data;
       if(OnPasoDatos != null) OnPasoDatos(data);   //Ahora, enviamos el dato al otro formulario donde nos tendremos que suscribir a este evento para poder recibir el dato
      }

    }
}
```

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

Boolean activo = false;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadStart delegado = new ThreadStart(proceso1);
    Thread hilo = new Thread(delegado);


    if (activo)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hilo abortado");
        hilo.Abort();
        activo = false;
    }
    else
    {
        hilo.Start();
        activo = true;
    }
}


private void proceso1()
{
    TelnetServer t = new TelnetServer(); //Creamos un objeto del tipo TelnetServer para poder suscribirnos al evento y recibir los datos de la otra clase
    t.OnPasoDatos+=reciboDatos; //Nos suscribimos al evento, esto quiere decir que cada vez que se ejecute el evento en la otra clase vendrá aquí.
}

public void reciboDatos(string texto){  //Esta es la función de callback
    label1.Text = texto;          //Asignamos a label el texto enviado desde la otra clase
}
}
```

Si no entiendes algo te lo puedo explicar, lo que te recomendaría es que mirases un poco como funcionan los eventos porque son muy útiles

Comment: Voy a volver a editar el comentario por que creo que no se ha entendido lo que busco , lo siento.  Aún así, lo que necesito es modificar el label, Telnet abre un socket, y mediante un comando empiezo a recibir mensajes desde un servidor, esos mensajes hacen referencia a un valor numerico, lo que tengo que mostrar en el label es el último valor numérico recibido.

Comment: aaaaa, ok ok, ahora te edito la respuesta y te lo pongo con eventos, ahora si que nos hemos entendido jajaja

Comment: te ha servido alguna respuesta?

Comment: Ahora si, muchas gracias, siento haber tardado en responder. :) Era eso justo lo que buscaba!

Comment: Me alegro, como te he dicho, los eventos van muy bien según para que cosas, a utilizar eventos se ha dicho! =)

Comment: Ya veo ya jaja, gracias. Indagaré más sobre el tema a ver si consigo añadir funcionalidades al proyecto y demás.

Answer (score 1):

Usando eventos para resolver tu problema, aquí te dejo mi ejemplo

```
//Esta vendria a ser tu clase TelnetServer
public class TelnetServer{
    //Evento lanzado cuando la operación de abrirTelnet no da error y pasa satisfactoriamente
    public event SuccessOperation OnSuccess;

    //Establezco el constructor
    public Telnet(){
        //Inicializo el evento para cuando lo llame si no se le ha asignado nada no de error
        OnSucess += Telnet_OnSuccess;
    }

    //Función llamada al ejecutarse el evento de que todo esta bien al llamar a la función abrirTelnet
    private void Telnet_OnSuccess(){ }

    //La puse public solamente, removí el static para tener acceso al evento
    public void abrirTelnet(){
       /* 
        * Tu código va aquí
        */
       //Esta condición es para que compruebes que se conectó, que abrió la ventana de telnet, en resumen que tu código de arriba esta ok   
       if(todo_esta_bien){
         //Lanzo el evento
         OnSuccess();
       }
    }
}

//Creo el delegado para ser usado en el evento
public delegate void SuccessOperation;
```

En tu formulario, es decir en Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Boolean activo = false;
    private TelnetServer telnet;

    public Form1(){
       InitializeComponent();
       //Creo una instancia de la clase TelnetServer para ser usada posteriormente
       telnet = new Telnet();
       //Aqui pongo el código a ejecutar cuando se lanza el evento OnSuccess
       telnet.OnSuccess += Telnet_OnSuccess;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart delegado = new ThreadStart(proceso1);
        Thread hilo = new Thread(delegado);


        if (activo)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hilo abortado");
            hilo.Abort();
            activo = false;
        }
        else
        {
            hilo.Start();
            activo = true;
        }
    }

    private void proceso1()
    {
        telnet.abrirTelnet();
    }

}
```

En resumen: Hago varias cosas, 1 cambio a public void tu función abrirTelnet, la tenias como static, al agregar eventos necesito instanciar la clase, 2 creo un delegado para ser usado como evento en la clase TelnetServer, 3 en el constructor de la clase telnet asigno una función vacía al evento OnSuccess, 4 creo la función que voy a asignar, 5 creo la variable privada telnetServer para poder trabajar con las propiedades de ese objeto desde Form1, 6 creo la función que se encargará de ejecutarse cuando el evento del TelnetServer se dispare en Form1.

Solo tienes que copiar y pegar. Pero indaga un poco más que tu problema se dará en multiples ocasiones.

Comment: He editado el código, no sé si así queda más claro, por que esto no lo entiendo del todo, Telnet no es un objeto y... es una clase que alberga metodos estáticos.

Comment: Me parece que expliqué bien inclusive mi código se parece bastante al tuyo. Dejame ponertelo más sencillo

Comment: No entiendo por que estas creando el objeto telnet=new Telnet();  Tampoco entiendo por que haces el OnSucces = () => { no le veo sentido a esos operadores, y bueno el label1.text. Lo único que necesito es saber como establecer el texto a la label de la clase Form

Comment: @AritzBello la respuesta no la probe, pero a simple vista parece correcta. Lo que estas pidiendo se resuelve de esta forma. No es trivial cuando usas hilos modificar lo que esta en otro thread, y menos lo que esta en otro form. Si tienes dudas sobre todo ese codigo, tal vez tengas que revisar lo que estas haciendo de otra forma. Esto es una tarea escolar?

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas no probe tu respuesta, sin embargo no genera un error al lanzar el evento ya que esta en otro thread (es pregunta, desconozco si no causa un error de acceso por otro thread)

Comment: @gbianchi es una tarea "empresarial" mas o menos, soy alumno en practicas, y en mi empresa me han pedido un programa, como aún no he terminado los estudios aún hay cosas que me parecen triviales, supongo, voy a verlo a ver si lo entiendo.

Comment: @AritzBello ok. Entonces te recomiendo leer sobre threads, llamadas cruzadas, eventos y pasajes de parametros. Todo eso tienes que aprender para resolver lo que estas necesitando. Y si no entiendes esta solucion, es porque te faltan entender conceptos. Y Tranquilo, todos tuvimos que empezar por algun lado, y muchos de estos conceptos no los aprenderas en la UNI...

Comment: @gbianchi probablemente me falte entender los conceptos... pero debe de haber alguna manera de abordar este problema de alguna otra manera, en la solución que me habéis dicho no veo en que momento pasas un valor string al label. Es decir, el thread recoge constantemente una serie de datos, y yo sigo sin ver en el ejemplo la forma en la que mando un string desde ese metodo, solo veo que se manda un evento, pero con ese evento yo no consigo nada. **Lo que necesito es**  if(String.contains("Algo"){ Form1.label1.text= variabletipostring;

Comment: Si, con ese evento consigues todo. Tu form recibe ese evento cada vez que se ejecuta, y ahi modificas el valor del label, tomando lo que contenga la clase y te pase como parametro el evento. Lo que falta aqui es el proceso que recibe el evento en el form para escribir el thread.