# Como saber si un evento se dispara antes de tener un suscriptor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, eventos, socket

Estoy teniendo problemas utilizando eventos. Estuve trabajando en base a una respuesta realizada aqui. Dejo el enlace mas abajo.
Estoy desarrollando un aplicacion de escritorio, lo que necesito es modificar el label, SocketServer es un servidor de escucha, que recibe mensajes desde un cliente, esos mensajes hacen referencia a un string, lo que tengo que mostrar en el label es el valor recibido.

[Acceder a una label desde otra clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110356/como-puedo-acceder-a-una-label-desde-otra-clase)

La cosa es que, no entra al metodo reciboDatos, tampoco tengo errores.

**MainWIndow.xaml.cs**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadStart delegado = new ThreadStart(proceso1);
            Thread hilo = new Thread(delegado);


            if (activo)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hilo abortado");
                hilo.Abort();
                activo = false;
                
            }
            else
            {
                hilo.Start();
                activo = true;
            }

        }

        private void proceso1()
        {

            SocketServer ss = new SocketServer();
            Console.WriteLine("Esta en proceso1");
            ss.OnPasoDatos += reciboDatos;
            Console.WriteLine("Tiene Suscriptor");

       }

        public void reciboDatos(string data)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Entro a reciboDatos: " + data);
            lblValue.Content = data;
        }
```

**SocketServer.cs**

```
public class SocketServer
    {
        public event pasoDatosHandler OnPasoDatos;
        public SocketServer()
        {
            OnPasoDatos += SocketServer_OnPasoDatos;
        }

        private void SocketServer_OnPasoDatos(string data)
        {

        }

        public static void StartServer()
        {
                   //Configuracion del servidor
                    Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);

                    SocketServer ss = new SocketServer();
                        
                    ss.AbrirDato(data);
                    
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }      

        public void AbrirDato(string data)
        {       
         if (data != null)
            {
                if (OnPasoDatos != null)
                {
                    OnPasoDatos(data);
                    Console.WriteLine("Entro a OnPasoDatos" + data);
                }
            }

        }

        public delegate void pasoDatosHandler(string data);
    }
```

Mi pregunta es, como se puede saber si el evento se dispara antes de suscribirse? Porque en el output veo que llega hasta proceso1 pero no pasa a reciboDatos.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer acerca de [eventos en c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/events/), esa lectura está en español.